# Translation length functions of non-simplicial trees

Tags: gr.group-theory, geometric-group-theory, trees

Let $G$ be a finitely generated group. By a theorem of Culler and Morgan, the set of non-abelian (not necessarily simplicial) minimal $\mathbb{R}$-trees with isometric $G$-action injects into the infinite-dimensional vector space $\mathbb{R}^G$ by assigning to each non-abelian tree $T$ its translation length function $l_T\colon G\to\mathbb{R},\ g\mapsto l_T(g)=\inf_{x\in T}d(x,gx)$.

Is there a way to read off of $l_T\in\mathbb{R}^G$ if $T$ is simplicial? For example, if the entries of $l_T$ are bounded below by some positive constant $c>0$, can $T$ still be non-simplicial?

Here, by a *simplicial* tree I mean an $\mathbb{R}$-tree whose set of vertices (i.e. points that when removed disconnect the tree into more than two components) is discrete and closed.

Comment: First, if you want an injection, you certainly should restrict to minimal actions. Also, I don't know what an abelian tree is. Why do you expect simplicial to be related to boundedness? Shouldn't it be related to   integrality? Finally, $l_T$ is not a length function (length is usually supposed to be subadditive, but for your $l=l_T$ you can have $l(g)=l(h)=0\neq l(gh)$).

Comment: If by simplicial you mean a simplicial tree with real edge lengths, then I think by Lyndon-Chiswell theory you get a simplicial action with the same length function iff  the image of the translation length is discrete.  I'm assuming the action is minimal so that the translation length determines the action. You might also want to used the based version.

Comment: @Sebastian: you should also provide a precise definition to simplicial. If you start with an action on a simplicial tree (with edges of length 1) and multiply the distance on the tree by $\sqrt{2}$, do you call the resulting $\mathbb{R}$-tree simplicial? etc. Please give a definition.

Comment: I updated the original post.

Comment: Sebastian: Take a look at Chiswell's book "Introduction to $\Lambda$-trees", chapter 4, where he described construction of the tree from the length function $\ell$ on $G$. I think, if you follow the arguments, discreteness of the set of values of $\ell$ will imply discreteness of the tree.

Comment: Sebastian: Let me know if it works, if not, I have an alternative approach.

Comment: Yes, it works: If the image of $l$ is discrete then the image of any based length function $L$ of $T$ is discrete. One then easily sees that Chiswell's construction yields a tree with discrete vertex set. Nevertheless, I would still be very interested in your alternative approach!

Comment: Sebastian: Does it also work under the weaker assumption that translation lengths are bounded below? This is the most natural hypothesis.

Comment: Here is the alternative approach: Given a discrete length function (I think, it suffices to assume it us bounded below) one defines a discrete pretree on which the group still acts. This discrete pretree extends canonically to a discrete tree, so the group still acts. This was worked out by Bowditch and Guirardel long ago.

Comment: I guess the last few comments concern based length functions (not translation length). What do you call "bounded below"? Is it gibberish for "proper"?

Comment: @YvesCornulier: Yves, sorry for being so nontransparent, but bounded below simply means that there is a positive number $a$ so that each nonzero (unbased) translation length is $\ge a$.

Comment: If I followed the comment thread correctly, this question has been resolved.  Perhaps someone could post an answer which can be accepted?

Answer (score 1):

A partial answer: suppose in addition that there are *finitely many
orbits of branch points*. (Branch point = vertex in the OQ.) This condition has been
considered by Jiang and Guirardel. For example Jiang
showed that this condition is satisfied if the given minimal action (of f.g.
$G$ on an $\mathbb{R}$-tree) is free.

Note $\ell(g)\leq L_x(g)=d(x,gx)$ for all $x\in X$, so if the
non-zero values of $\ell$ are bounded away from zero by $c$ then
$d(x,gx)>c$ for all $x\in X$ and $g\in G$, that is, orbits of each
point are discrete. Therefore the set of all branch points, as a
finite union of closed and discrete subsets is closed and discrete.

In the opposite direction, if $x$ is a branch point and $c_x>0$ such
that every other branch point is further from $x$ than $c_x$, then
$L_x(g)> c_x$ for all $g$ that doesn't fix $x$. Since $L_{\gamma
x}(g)=L_x(\gamma^{-1}g\gamma)$, the number $c_x$ depends only on the orbit, not
on $x$ itself. Choosing $c_x$ for each orbit and taking the minimum
$c$ we get $L_x(g)=d(x,gx)>c$ for all branch points $x$.

However, making the step from $L_x(g)$ bounded away from zero to
$\ell(g)$ bounded away from zero requires more input.

Comment: Thank you, this is enlightening. Unfortunately, having only finitely many orbits of branch points seems to be a condition that is, in general, hard to check. As pointed out in my comment above, the image of $ l $ being discrete seems to suffice. It would be interesting to know if the values of $ l $ being bounded below also does.

Comment: I've deleted an observation to the effect that an action may
be simplicial even if the image of $\ell$ is not discrete.
Unfortunately, the example originally given doesn't support this.

Comment: @shane.orourke if the action is simplicial (and minimal), then since $\Gamma$ is f.g., Bass-Serre theory tells you that there are finitely many edge orbits, and hence finitely many edge lengths. So the set of translations lengths (i.e. the image of $\ell$) is contained in the semigroup of $\mathbf{R}$ generated by these finitely many positive elements, and hence is discrete.

Answer (score 0):

This question has been answered by Misha, in the comments, as follows.

> Given a discrete length function (I think, it suffices to assume it us bounded below) one defines a discrete pretree on which the group still acts. This discrete pretree extends canonically to a discrete tree, so the group still acts. This was worked out by Bowditch and Guirardel long ago

Comment: In an answer it would have been nice to be a little less sloppy...

Comment: @YvesCornulier - I don't have time to be more careful. But the answer is CW, so feel free to improve it!

Comment: I'll try if I find some time but I'd first need to understand the picture correctly.

Comment: I am still worried about this answer. If the branch points of $T$ are a discrete pretree then $T$ must be discrete. The pretree structure on the branch points of $T$ is described in "Parry - Axioms for Translation Length Functions"; it is discrete if $max\left\{ 0 , l(xy) - l(x) - l(y)\right\}$ is discrete, where $x,y$ range over all hyperbolic elements of $G$. Each summand in $l(xy) - l(x) - l(y)$ is discrete if $l$ is discrete. But linear combinations of discrete functions need not be discrete; think of $l(xy)$ taking values which are multiples of $\sqrt{2}$ and $l(x)$ taking integer values.